# Drop multiple columns from DataFrame recursively in SPARK <= version 1.6.0

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I want to drop multiple cols from the data frame in one go. Don't want to write .drop("col1").drop("col2").

Note: I am using spark-1.6.0

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is available in the current spark version (2.0 onwards) and for earlier version we can make use of the below code.

1.

```
    implicit class DataFrameOperation(df: DataFrame) {
            def dropCols(cols: String*): DataFrame = {
               @tailrec def deleteCol(df: DataFrame, cols: Seq[String]): DataFrame = 
               if(cols.size == 0) df else deleteCol(df.drop(cols.head), cols.tail)
        deleteCol(df, cols)
}
}
```

2. To call the method

   ```
   val finalDF = dataFrame.dropCols("col1","col2","col3")
   ```

Comment: Presumably this `DataFrameOperation` were inside an object .. and then client code would need to first `import DataFrameOperationContainer._` ?

Comment: You are correct.. It should be like below.
object DataFrameOperations {
    implicits......
}

and after that need to import to avail the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This method is a work around method.

```
public static DataFrame drop(DataFrame dataFrame, List<String> dropCol) {
    List<String> colname = Arrays.stream(dataFrame.columns()).filter(col -> !dropCol.contains(col)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    // colname list will have the names of the cols except the ones to be dropped.
    return dataFrame.selectExpr(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(colname));
}
```

inputDataFrame:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| C0| C1| C2| C3| C4|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|
|  1|  5|  6|  0| 14|
|  1|  6|  1|  0|  3|
|  1|  0|  1|  0|  1|
|  1| 37|  9|  0| 19|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If you want to drop C0, C2, C4 columns,

colDroppedDataFrame:

```
+---+---+
| C1| C3|
+---+---+
|  0|  0|
|  5|  0|
|  6|  0|
|  0|  0|
| 37|  0|
+---+---+
```